# Wordpress Back End TypeError: t.parsed.responses[0] is undefined in Categories

Tags: ajax, wordpress, categories

I'm developing on a theme But stuck with a problem 
when I add New Category from admin panel It needs page to be reload. I've got 
TypeError: t.parsed.responses[0] is undefined  in the console. 
Need help

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to fix this problem - this problem in the your theme's directory in the functions.php file:

/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/functions.php - restore backup of this file and your problem will be fix

P.S. Sorry for my Eng - im from russia